# Custom authentication against SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sql-server, authentication

I have a WPF application and a SQL Server database with a `Users` table. Every user has it's own row including hashed password and role in `Users` table.

I need to let them authenticate in my application and keep some kind of credentials, including role. Based on that role, they will see only what they should see.

Can you give me some clue how to accomplish it? What is the best way to keep those credentials and hide parts of my application based on user's role?

Thanks for any help, JiKra

---

Ok, I was thinking and how about to use a singleton? User authenticates, I grab his role from database, instantiate a singleton, set his credentials and use them in my app.
Is that correct? It's the easiest way to do that?
JiKra

Comment: Is this a two tier application where the WPF client talks directly to the database or a three tier application where the WPF client talks to webserver/service which talks to the database?

Comment: Examine the excellent multi-part series on [ASP.NET Membership and Role subsystem](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) - you can use if from WPF, too - no problem - and it's already there, it's available, it works and it's proven its value thousands of times over.

Comment: Jared: I use datasets to talk directly to the database.

Comment: marc: I can't imagine, how to use asp.net membership in wpf. To be clear, I'm a bit of beginer, my app is realy simple, and I need a quick and simple solution...

Comment: You should be aware that if you are talking directly to the database, you can essentially have no real security.  This is because the application on the desktop will have to have the connection string somewhere, and an end user could always look at that connection string and manually access the database to view all users and their passwords.

Comment: Passwords are stored in SHA1 hash and security is not a big issue. What I need is role based functional model. Users will use only parts of my application, based on their role.

Comment: @JiKra: And what credentials are used to connect to the database from the application? The application has to somehow first connect to the database to validate users credentials stored in the table. And this "somehow" is a security hole - anyone knowing these fixed credentials will be able to use any technology (osql.exe/custom code) to connect to the database.

Comment: Wiktor: I use Windows Integrated Security, so that would be a windows credentials, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "functional model" as you call it can be based on the `MembershipProvider`/`RoleProvider` APIs. There's a tutorial video by Todd Miranda:

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=293710

What the tutorial lacks is where you should store the information so that it's available for the other parts of the application. The answer is simple - since you have the stateful application, you can store the information in a shared (static) resource in a class.

Please also be aware of a potential security risk, I've added a comment under your question.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look. Some static class or a singleton is what I thought to be a solution...

Comment: @JiKra: in reference to your comment, if your application relies on integrated security then what you store additional passwords for?